# activity onpause is getting called twice

Tags: android

i am experiencing a weird issue after making changes in my application code and my app is recompiled...onPause activity lifecycle method runs for second time after about 20 seconds from the initial run...have anyone experienced a similar issue?

activity where onPause is called twice:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NetworkStateListeners, LoginActivityCommonElementsAndMuchMore {

private static final String debugTag = LoginActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder;
private StyleSpan styleSpan;
private SignInFragment signInFragment;
private RegisterFragment registerFragment;
private ForgotPasswordFragment forgotPasswordFgmt;
private ClickableSpan clickableSpan;
private Bundle loginActivityBundle;
private int connectionStatus;
private NetworkState networkState;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.e(debugTag, "onCreate");
    setContentView(R.layout.login_activity);

    if ( savedInstanceState == null ) {
        networkState        =   new NetworkState();
        loginActivityBundle =   new Bundle();

        signInFragment = new SignInFragment();
        signInFragment.setArguments(loginActivityBundle);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, signInFragment, getResources().getString(R.string.signInFgmt))
                .commit();

        getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBackStackChanged() {
                Log.d(debugTag, "BACK STACK CHANGED!");
                Log.d(debugTag, "BACK STACK COUNT: " + getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());
                for (int i = 0; i < getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount(); i++) {
                    Log.d(debugTag, "BACK STACK ENTRIES: " + getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(i).getName());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.e(debugTag, "onResume");
    networkState.addListener(this);
    registerReceiver(networkState, new IntentFilter(getResources().getString(R.string.connectivity_change)));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.e(debugTag, "onPause");
    networkState.removeListener(this);
    unregisterReceiver(networkState);
    int x = 10;
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    RefWatcher refWatcher = MyApplication.getRefWatcher(this);
    refWatcher.watch(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    if ( getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0 ) getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(0, 0);
}

@Override
public void setLoginActivitySpan(TextView textView, String stringResource, int start, int end, final int code) {
    spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(stringResource);
    styleSpan = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
    clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {

        }
    };
    spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(clickableSpan, start, end, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(styleSpan, start, end, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.loginSpanColor)), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    textView.setText(spannableStringBuilder);
}

@Override
public void forgotPasswordOnClick() {
    forgotPasswordFgmt = new ForgotPasswordFragment();
    forgotPasswordFgmt.setArguments(loginActivityBundle);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame_container, forgotPasswordFgmt, getResources().getString(R.string.forgotPasswordFgmt))
            .addToBackStack(getResources().getString(R.string.forgotPasswordFgmt))
            .commit();
}

@Override
public void registerOnClick() {
    registerFragment = new RegisterFragment();
    if ( getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0 ) getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    loginActivityBundle.putInt("connectivityStatus", connectionStatus);
    registerFragment.setArguments(loginActivityBundle);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame_container, registerFragment, getResources().getString(R.string.registerFgmt))
            .addToBackStack(getResources().getString(R.string.registerFgmt))
            .commit();
}

@Override
public void signInHereOnClick() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}

public static SharedPreferences getSessionPrefs(Context context) {
    //Mode private so only this app can modify this SharedPreferences file
    SharedPreferences sessionPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(AppConfig.SESSION_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sessionPrefs;
}

@Override
public boolean validateEditText(EditText[] fields) {
    for (EditText field : fields) {
        if (field.getText().toString().isEmpty() && field.getTag().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.required))) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String encodeUtf8(String text) {
    try {
        byte[] data = text.getBytes("UTF-8");
        return Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public String decodeUtf8(String text) {
    try {
        byte[] data = Base64.decode(text, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return new String(data, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void networkStatus(int connectionType) {
    Log.e(debugTag, "listeners: "+connectionType);
    connectionStatus = connectionType;
    Intent intent = new Intent(getResources().getString(R.string.network_state_update));
    intent.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.connectivity_status), connectionStatus);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

}

logcat:

```
   03-21 15:10:35.842 20756-20756/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem        E/LoginActivity: onCreate
03-21 15:10:36.062 20756-20756/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem E/LoginActivity: onResume
03-21 15:10:36.082 20756-20851/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
03-21 15:10:36.092 20756-20756/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem E/com.votingsystem.tsiro.broadcastReceivers.NetworkState: onReceive
03-21 15:10:36.092 20756-20756/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem E/com.votingsystem.tsiro.broadcastReceivers.NetworkState: notifyState Called
03-21 15:10:36.092 20756-20756/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem E/LoginActivity: listeners: 0
03-21 15:10:36.102 20756-20756/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
03-21 15:10:36.102 20756-20756/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
03-21 15:10:36.132 20756-20756/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem D/SRIB_DCS: log_dcs ThreadedRenderer::initialize entered! 
03-21 15:10:36.142 20756-20851/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem I/Adreno: EGLInit: QTI Build: 06/19/15, 9723ec1, I4ea93f0e25
03-21 15:10:36.152 20756-20851/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-21 15:10:36.162 20756-20851/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem D/OpenGLRenderer: Get maximum texture size. GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE is 16384
03-21 15:10:36.162 20756-20851/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
03-21 15:10:36.442 20756-20756/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@32d079c3 time:682299231
03-21 15:10:46.112 20756-20756/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem E/LoginActivity: onPause
03-21 15:10:46.322 20756-20756/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem E/LoginActivity: onResume
03-21 15:10:46.352 20756-20756/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem E/com.votingsystem.tsiro.broadcastReceivers.NetworkState: onReceive
03-21 15:10:46.352 20756-20756/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem E/com.votingsystem.tsiro.broadcastReceivers.NetworkState: notifyState Called
03-21 15:10:46.352 20756-20756/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem E/LoginActivity: listeners: 0
03-21 15:10:46.352 20756-20756/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@32d079c3 time:682309143
```

Comment: put your complete activity code where your onpause is getting called twice?

Comment: i did it right now..

Comment: It is getting called after an onResume or is it just an onPause call?  onResume/onPause cycles are common.

Comment: ok thanks, can i also have logcat so get better idea about logs you have print in your activity.

Comment: OnResume will be called when your activity is in active state, means user is doing some I/O interaction with your activity. while onPause will be called when some dialog or another activity comes on top of the activity.

Comment: @DeeV it is a onResume->onPause->onResume cycle..

Comment: @SilvansSolanki i know when its method is called but in my case something else is going wrong..

Comment: @tsiro:  This can be caused by a lot of things. It means something else is coming up and your app is being paused for a (very brief) bit. A background app could be starting an activity that immediately returns for example.  It may be better in your case to use `onStart()/onStop()` instead.

Comment: yes but this is happening only when my app is recompiled and not every time is being run..

Comment: `LoginActivityCommonElementsAndMuchMore` that is a creative name

Comment: @TimCastelijns what do you mean by saying 'LoginActivityCommonElementsAndMuchMore errors aside'?